# Include MySQL Connector/J in a commercial product

Tags: licensing, gpl-2

There are a few questions about MySQL licensing already out there, but none of them have a definitive "yes" or "no" answer, so with the risk of being flagged as "duplicate", I will ask my question as clear as possible:

**Can I bundle the MySQL Connector/J JAR file with my commercially (closed source) product?**

Background: The MySQL Connector/J license is GPL2, which requires me to include MY source if it's a derivative work. But it's not a derivative work. It would be used as a library, not a compile-time dependency. Does this fall under "mere aggregation"?

Comment: Have you read the [GPL FAQ on aggregation](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.en.html#MereAggregation)? "If modules are designed to run linked together in a shared address space, that almost surely means combining them into one program."

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL Connector/J License](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/13287/mysql-connector-j-license) or [MySQL for Commercial Web Application](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/7877/mysql-for-commercial-web-application)

Comment: I think this question is more about "does (dynamic) linking create a derivative work" rather than the specifics of the MySQL licensing. We've got duplicates of that as well of course :)

Comment: The [Web Application answer](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/7877/mysql-for-commercial-web-application) is not exactly relevant, as the OP does not distribute his project, and I would. The closest is the [Discord Bot answer](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/13287/mysql-connector-j-license).

@PhilipKendall It looks like that is more the case indeed. Eventually it becomes a semanctical discussion of "linking" vs "using a library", and I'd rather not have this discussion with the Oracle Legal Team…

Comment: I appreciate that question/answer may not have the definitive answer you want. But the real world doesn't always have definitive answers, sometimes you have to deal with uncertainty. The simple way to avoid any discussion with the Oracle legal team is just not to use the MySQL connector...

Comment: @SurfMan If you don't want to risk a call from Oracle, just use MariaDB or another relational database with a connector under LGPL or a permissive license.

Comment: Mere aggregation means mere aggregation. Mere = nothing more than. Aggregation = putting two things under one roof. The original intention was to let you put lots of different software (some GPL and some not) onto a CD and give away the CD with your magazine so the people who bought the magazine could try lots of different software. It should be obvious this doesn't apply to a library used by a program.

Comment: @user253751 Your interpretation of 'mere aggregation' seems to be overly strict, even FSF have a more relaxed view on this: https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.html#MereAggregation

Comment: I thank everybody for contributing. Based on this information I will *not* be using the MySQL Connector/J. It's just too vague and too much of a liability (Thanks Oracle!).